# Using AVFoundation to record video then upload it to parse.com

Tags: ios, video, parse-platform, avfoundation, video-recording

I am using AVFoundation to record video then allow user to draw on it, then upload it to parse.com.

My issue is parse API needs NSDATA to upload video to server, but I don't know how I can make NSData from AVFoundation.  This my last code (I main apply draw on video ) {

```
- (void)applyVideoEffectsToComposition:(AVMutableVideoComposition *)composition size:(CGSize)size
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_super_view.bounds.size);
    [_super_view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    /// end

    // 1 - set up the overlay
    CALayer *overlayLayer = [CALayer layer];
    UIImage *overlayImage = nil;

    overlayImage =image;

    [overlayLayer setContents:(id)[overlayImage CGImage]];
    overlayLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 640,920 );
    [overlayLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];

    // 2 - set up the parent layer
    CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
    CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];
    parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,0,0);
    videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 640,920);
    [parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];
    [parentLayer addSublayer:overlayLayer];

    // 3 - apply magic
    composition.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool
                                 videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];


}
```

Then what can i do to upload video to server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the AVAssetExportSession to do this:

```
AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:composition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
exporter.outputURL=url;
 exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
 exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
 [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
   //Video is saved to file path
    });
}];
```

`url` is an NSURL with a file path.

Once the file is saved to the file path you can fetch it using 
    [NSData initWithContentsOfURL:url]

Then convert the NSData into a PFFile and you are good to go!

Comment: Thank you , for ur help , but (exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:) take time for a long video or also short video some time .. , So any way to make it faster ?

Comment: Unfortunately to be able to use the video you will have to export, which basically converts the video into a more commonly known video format rather than the composition you have created. There isn't a way around it. However, this entire process is done asynchronously so your user wont actually have to wait till the process is done.

Comment: I am trying `var videoFile = new Parse.File("movie.mov", {base64:request.params.data})` but I can still not get the PFFile to save...how did you succeed?